# How do I build a carousel image slider using MVC cshtml?

Tags: javascript, razor

I am trying to code a carousel image slider in MVC using cshtml, the pictures are only displaying in one vertical row and isn't populating into the Carousel slider itself?
Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
Html.Raw("<link href='../../Content/Site.css' rel='stylesheet'>")
@Html.Raw("<script src='../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>")
```

### Products

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $('#slider').cycle({ fx: 'fade', speed: 'fast', timeout: 0, next: '#next2', prev: '#prev2' });
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/feature-carousel.css" charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/css/feature-carousel.css" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="Content/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Content/js/jquery.featureCarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var carousel = $("#carousel").featureCarousel({


                // include options like this:
                // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
                // option: value,
                // option: value
            });

            $("#but_prev").click(function () {
                carousel.prev();
            });
            $("#but_pause").click(function () {
                carousel.pause();
            });
            $("#but_start").click(function () {
                carousel.start();
            });
            $("#but_next").click(function () {
                carousel.next();
            });
        });
    </script>


          <center>



                    <div class="carousel-container"></div>

                        <div id="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-feature">
                                <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="~/Images/1.jpg" /></a>
                                <div class="carousel-caption">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-feature">
                                <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="~/Images/2.jpg"></a>
                                <div class="carousel-caption">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-feature">
                                <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="~/Images/3.jpg"></a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-feature">
                                <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="~/Images/4.jpg"></a>
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-feature">
                                <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Image Caption" src="~/Images/5.jpg"></a>
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="carousel-left"><img src="~/Content/images/arrow-left.png" /></div>
                            <div id="carousel-right"><img src="~/Content/images/arrow-right.png" /></div>
                        </div>

           </center>
```

Comment: Maybe your JavaScript plugin isn't loading properly?  Check the browser console for errors.  When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?

Comment: The application runs.I am using Visual Studio. the plugin's are all installed in my application using Nuget. its stored under my scripts folder. i have installed jquery and bootsrap .

Comment: What all of that tells me is that you *assume* it should be working.  Clearly something isn't working.  So... maybe actually debug it and find out what's wrong?  Don't assume that just because you think you installed something that it therefore *must* be working.  At least *look* at the browser console for errors.  Nobody here can debug your application on your computer for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. but like i said, i did debug it, just the pictures appear in one row...Thanks...

Comment: @Melanie i have put solution here please try it and let me know.

Comment: @JaiminSoni i removed the extra's... it still isn't showing the slider..

Comment: @Melanie put the script tag code at the end of the view page.

Answer (score 0):

I found there are multiple jQuery references in view.

```
    <script src='../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <script src="Content/js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Remove multiple jQuery references from the view.

Only one is enough.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing all the images need to be the same size, which is why it isn't populating on the slider?....